# Tensorflow predict/train step has massive slowdown after ~1.5k training iterations with high RAM usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am new to Tensorflow, and trying to train a RL model to play a pygame game.

I followed [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-reinforcement-learning-with-python-part-2-creating-training-the-rl-agent-using-deep-q-d8216e59cf31) and adapted it for my game.

The training runs one step in the environment, then a model.predict and a model.fit call with batch size 128, randomly sampling previous plays.

The training starts well, but after many iterations of the above (~1.5k over about 5 hours), the training suddenly grinds to a halt and the python process's RAM usage is about 9.5GB. Leaving for over a day it never returns to the previous speed:

```
...
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
episode 1387/5000 reward:    -1833.2535652225936
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
...
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
4/4 [==============================] - 347s 116s/step
4/4 [==============================] - 347s 116s/step
4/4 [==============================] - 1641s 321s/step
4/4 [==============================] - 1352s 333s/step
4/4 [==============================] - 224s 48s/step
4/4 [==============================] - 224s 48s/step
4/4 [==============================] - 3951s 672s/step
4/4 [==============================] - 3942s 981s/step
```

I am training currently on a mac with M1 chip and tensorflow-metal installed - I believe it is using GPU acceleration (based on the output below)

```
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Apart from the high Memory usage there don't seem to be any resource constraints. I imagine it is the high memory use causing this, but I don't know the source of the high memory use either as I don't think I am doing anything out of the ordinary (opening many files without closing  properly for example) and I don't understand why the slow down would be so abrupt.

**More info from debugging:**

I ran the same code in debug so I could see what lines were causing the incredibly slow step.

It seems within model.predict (and model.fit I believe), the DataHandler class in `keras/engine/data_adapter.py` is causing the slow down. It seems even getting properties is slow, for example the line `original_spe = self._steps_per_execution.numpy().item()` takes about 30s to complete (running just self._steps_per_execution without the further function call has the same delay), same for `yield self._current_step`

What is going on?

**Things I've tried**

The main bit of advice I tried was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66165193). I did most of the steps here, although only running keras.backend.clear_session() every 100 episodes as that in itself is pretty slow.

I also read that pygame can cause problems if initialised and then not called for a long period of time, so I have removed the dependency on pygame.

**Setup**

```
System:
Device: MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)
Chip: Apple M1 Max
Memory: 32 GB
OS: macOS Monterey 12.3.1

Python:
3.10.3

Tensorflow:
tensorflow-macos==2.9.2
tensorflow-metal==0.5.0
keras==2.9.0
```

Comment: Are you using any callbacks? Can you post code on how you defined the model and any custom training loops you might have?

Comment: Sure, here is my code, including model definition:
https://github.com/arneyjfs/ai-tetris/
I do have a custom callback, as defined on [line 38 of model.py](https://github.com/arneyjfs/ai-tetris/blob/72f669a70cc20d5f56c813617810fbce2cb20bae/model.py#L37), but I believe even when removing this the issue was the same... not sure though

Comment: Try without the callback. The only reason I can this happening is with any process that affects training data, which would be either a callback or some IO process if you're reading from the hard drive.